# Errors setting up Google App Engine on Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: google-app-engine

So I have followed [This](http://nzbart.blogspot.com/2011/05/setting-up-google-app-engine.html) guide and used a simple printing python file. Problem is, when I run my dev_appserver.py file either through eclipse or in terminal i get the following errors:

```
/Desktop/%/google/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Desktop/%/google/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 77, in <module>
 run_file(__file__, globals())
File "/Desktop/%/google/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 73, in run_file
execfile(script_path, globals_)
File "/Desktop/%/google/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_main.py",    line 154, in <module>
from google.appengine.tools import appcfg
 File "/Desktop/%/google/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 68, in <module>
from google.appengine.tools import appengine_rpc
File "/Desktop/%/google/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appengine_rpc.py", line 27, in <module>
import fancy_urllib
File "/Desktop/%/google/google_appengine/lib/fancy_urllib/fancy_urllib/__init__.py", line 341, in <module>
class FancyHTTPSHandler(urllib2.HTTPSHandler):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'HTTPSHandler'
```

Has anyone else had a similar experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think ubuntu 11.04 uses Python3 so the module `HTTPSHandler` is now `urllib.request.HTTPSHandler` [source](http://docs.pythonsprints.com/python3_porting/py-porting.html)

Google AppEngine supports for the moment only Python2.5. So you need to install Python2.5

EDIT (sorry in your guide you have normaly already installed python2.5):

In your case i think you use always the environment of python 3.

1. try to execute a shell with python 2.5 to check if it installed correctly: `python2.5`
2. try to launch the dev_appserver with this command `python2.5 {GAE_DIR_ROOT}/dev_appserver.py`

Comment: Yes, running the app engine dev server with Python 2.5 should resolve this. Try running the dev server like this `python2.5 {GAE_DIR_ROOT}/dev_appserver.py` instead of just `{GAE_DIR_ROOT}/dev_appserver.py`

Comment: Thanks for your help, using this method i can get the server to run, but when i browse to http://localhost:8080 i get the errors as above!

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 11.04 comes with python 2.6 as the default version. It is suggested to use Google app engine with version 2.5. I am using it though for many years with python 2.6 without any issues.

What you need to do in order to execute it smoothly with python 2.6 is to edit `google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py` and add these three lines

```
  '_counter',
  '_fastmath',
  'strxor',
```

after `'XOR',` and before `'_Crypto_Cipher__AES',` around line 1350. A simple text search will

Comment: line 1350?!! my dev_appserver.py has only 77 lines